# How to Represent System in UML?

Tags: architecture, uml, system, modeling

We can use Subsystem element to show breakdown of systems in UML.
And, we can group Components into Subsystems.

But, is there a element to represent a system?

System here means the superset of Subsystems.

Comment: What, in your terms, would be  a _system_?

Comment: Well, a _superset_ (you probably mean just _set_) will not necessarily make a system. You can have a set of subsystems that still are subsystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system is just a component, that is composed of subsystems. And in a system of systems it will itself be a subsystem. So, each component is always at the same time a system and a subsystem - it just depends on the *viewpoint* of the modeler. Therefore the same diagrams can be used to show the decomposition of systems and subsystems.

In order to show, which of the components is the system of interest from *your* viewpoint, you can create a `«system»` stereotype, as suggested by @Christophe. Strangely enough, there is no standard stereotype for this, not even in SysML.

Comment: Same comment here as below...

Comment: @qwerty_so: Yes, there is some effort necessary to create a profile. However, most projects will have their custom profile anyway, so, the stereotype can just be added there. And also, it's not that hard to create one, at least if you have a good modeling tool. In fact, I do use a «system» stereotype in most of my projects.

Comment: I do have my profiles. But I guess that the procedure to create one is not something present for any common UML user. EA introduced real profiles only recently. Still you can create "wild" stereotypes which I would guess is still common practice. Just to object that. Btw. I still think that the OP has not reflected about _system_. It's such a common term that everybody seems to know its meaning. But actually it's not the same in reality. Well...

Answer (score 1):

The only UML diagram where you see the system in the outside world is the use-case diagram. The system under consideration is represented by a surrounding box in which the use-cases are showed.

In all other diagrams, we are supposed to show some system related internals and there is no notation (nor even  need) to show the whole system. In some structural diagrams, you can show larger subsystems. You show these as a component headed with the standard stereotype `«Subsystem»`.

Now, [boundaries of complex systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72064514/3723423) may be fuzzy: You may very well work on a very complex "system of systems". In this case you‘have a system made of other systems. From an UML perspective those other systems would simply be subsystems of the "system of systems".

If you need to make a clearer distinction between levels of subsystems, you could simply create an UML profile with a `«System»` stereotype. On the other extreme range, you could use [SysML with a dedicated SoS profile](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/smr.1878).

Comment: In order to create a stereotype you need to have a profile where the stereotype belongs to. Prpobably a bit of overtkill for this purpose.

Comment: I guess the term _system_ is not clearly defined by the OP.

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed, as stated, “*you could simply create a profile with a «System» profile*”. People routinely create profiles for using language specific types. Is it really an overkill to create a profile? If working on systems of systems, it’s a little pain for a great additional expressivity. The lain qjestion is whether it is really needed. If making a hierarchical decomposition of the system, just start with the first subsystem level below the system which is ilplicitly enclosing them.

Comment: @qwerty_so I will not blame OP: the system is arbitrary: you can consider it restrictively as an IT system. But you could zoom out and consider a group of related system as being the real system. And you could consider an organisational system made of the human, organisational and IT assets.  It’s because if the recursive definition of systems.

Comment: That's why I question the OP's understanding/self reflection. What is _his_ idea of a system. Usually you model the system under consideration and that would be understood as _system_. But the way the question is asked I doubt that the OP has made up his mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since a Subsystem is already a Stereotype of a Component in the Standard Profile, you just have to create a «System» Stereotype that also Extends the Component Metaclass in your own Profile.
This is considering that the scope your system is only software and hardware with no actor activity.
As Christophe mentioned, the only thing in UML representing the system is the subject which surrounds its Use Cases, the subject not even being a Model Element...

Comment: In order to create a stereotype you need to have a profile where the stereotype belongs to. Prpobably a bit of overtkill for this purpose.

Comment: Actually, the `subject` _is_ a model element. It is a property of `UseCase`. Any `Classifier` can be the `subject` of a `UseCase`. Therefore, the use case diagram also doesn't allow to model a system. We might think that the subject of a use case is the system of interest, but that is just an interpretation. What if the use case has multiple subjects?

Comment: Formally, as it can be seen in section 18.1 of the OMG Spec, Subject is not a Metaclass and the UseCase Metaclass has no attributes. However, this doesn't matter much here. Also, the 3rd sentence of section 18.1.1 states: "Each UseCase’s subject represents a system under consideration to which the UseCase applies.". My understanding is that a particular UseCase may be a part of more than 1 system. Therefore, the "shared" UseCase would be specified once for all systems it participates to.

Comment: Yes, `subject` is not a metaclass. The `UseCase` metaclass however _does_ have attributes, on of them being `subject`. Please keep in mind, that association ends with a dot are attributes of the class.

Comment: I didn't remember, that the specification explicitly mentions systems here and I like the quote, as it confirms my interpretation above. Still it might be usefull, to make the system more recognizable by adding a stereotype. If the use case has more than one subject it could be, that both systems are described in our model. It is also possible, that one of them is only briefly mentioned here and the model is mostly about the other. Then I need to make a distinction. Again, I could use a stereotype.

Comment: Thank you Axel for these useful clarifications.